# Make Autorization on app (Vocal recognition)

Tags: actions-on-google

I created an app on google home, and I want the app to work only if its MY voice who that asks to do the skills on my google home

How can i do that? Is this possible? I configured my google home at beginning for it recognize my voice, now how to make it mandatory for this app?

I'm trying to make my app secure because it's make banking operations by voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user request is sent to your application with a [unique anonymous UserID](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info#anonymous_user_identity). You will need to determine the UserID that belongs to your account (by looking at logs for your application to see which value is yours) and reject requests from other UserIDs.

Even better would be to setup a more proper [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) system.

Keep in mind, however, that the voice authentication system isn't perfect and there is a slight, but possible, way for others to duplicate the request - either by using a recording of your voice or by having a similar voice. Consider all the risks when designing such applications.